# my CSS class not applied to my div container?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem, the problem is I have a header, having multipls container like this :

```
<header>
    <div class="logo-and-social-media-container"></div>
    <div class="levels-container hideImp">
        <div class="first-level-container"></div>
        <div class="second-level-container"></div> 
    </div>
</header>
```

Inside those containers, there is html code generated by javascript with createElement et createNode texts, elements inside those containers have their own style. and it is working fine.

But this class is not applied:

```
.hideImp {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Why ? I don't know, I tried some things :

- I removed the cache but nothing seems to work
- I tried to remove all my css classes except this one to see if there is no contact between my html file and css file, but my html elements came back to their default styling by removing the css classes which means there is contact, so I had only one css file having only the property you see above but does not work.
- I tried to force the refresh, but I think that removing the cache is more efficient than this.

Also I tried this :

```
<header>
    <div class="logo-and-social-media-container"></div>
    <style>.hideImp {display: none !important;}</style>
    <div class="levels-container hideImp">
        <div class="first-level-container"></div>
        <div class="second-level-container"></div> 
    </div>
</header>
```

All I see in the inspector is that my div has its default display value *( `display: div;` )*

What is the problem ?

Comment: you may have the display set elsewhere, try to rename your div class

Comment: Can you *demonstrate* this not working in a Snippet?

Comment: I can't, this is just a simulation of what is happening to me

Comment: Botond : No, I verefied, I have only one class, and I copy paste it to my html element

Comment: For some reasons, God knows them, it worked when I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it, and the code was working in mozila and Opera. The question is not a duplicate, it is fine, clear why closing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well what I think is that you must try the following codes-

```
.levels-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Or you can try this also-

```
<div class="levels-container hideImp" style="display: none;">
```

Hoping that will help!!
Greetings,
Om Chaudhary